# How to match multiple lines using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

I am trying replace some content in a tex file, example bellow.

I would like to match the content from `\starttable` till second `\HL`.

```
\starttable[|lp(0.08\textwidth)|lp(0.35\textwidth)|lp(0.48\textwidth)|lp(0.08\textwidth)|]
\HL
\NC Req. Id
\NC Description
\NC Test Scenario
\NC Result
\NC\AR
\HL
\NC TAF-89

\NC Trigger test start - from jig

\NC 
\NC Unavailable

\NC\AR
\NC TAF-88

\NC Trigger test start - using scanner

\NC 
\NC Unavailable

\NC\AR
\HL
```

I tried with

```
Regex tableHeaderRegex = new Regex(@"(\\starttable(.*))(\\HL..(\\NC.*)+\\HL)",
                                 RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

But this does not stop at the second `\HL`, but goes on to match the last `\HL` because of `\\NC.*`

I have also tried the `RegexOptions.Multiline` but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\\starttable[\s\S]*?\\HL[\s\S]*?\\HL
```

You can use this without `g` flag to attain the same.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/41